# Is _mm256_store_ps() function is atomic ? while using alongside openmp

Tags: c, openmp, avx, avx2

I am trying to create a simple program that uses Intel's AVX technology and perform vector multiplication and addition. Here I am using Open MP alongside this. But it is getting segmentation fault due to the function call _mm256_store_ps().

I have tried with OpenMP atomic features like atomic, critical, etc so that if this function is atomic in nature and multiple cores are attempting to execute at the same time, but it is not working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<immintrin.h>
#include<omp.h>
#define N 64

__m256 multiply_and_add_intel(__m256 a, __m256 b, __m256 c) {
  return _mm256_add_ps(_mm256_mul_ps(a, b),c);
}

void multiply_and_add_intel_total_omp(const float* a, const float* b, const float* c, float* d)
{
  __m256 a_intel, b_intel, c_intel, d_intel;
  #pragma omp parallel for private(a_intel,b_intel,c_intel,d_intel)
  for(long i=0; i<N; i=i+8) {
    a_intel = _mm256_loadu_ps(&a[i]);
    b_intel = _mm256_loadu_ps(&b[i]);
    c_intel = _mm256_loadu_ps(&c[i]);
    d_intel = multiply_and_add_intel(a_intel, b_intel, c_intel);
    _mm256_store_ps(&d[i],d_intel);
  }
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    float * a = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * N);
    float * b = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * N);
    float * c = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * N);
    float * d_intel_avx_omp = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * N);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        a[i] = (float)(rand()%10);
        b[i] = (float)(rand()%10);
        c[i] = (float)(rand()%10);
    }
    double time_t = omp_get_wtime();
    multiply_and_add_intel_total_omp(a,b,c,d_intel_avx_omp);
    time_t = omp_get_wtime() - time_t;
    printf("\nTime taken to calculate with AVX2 and OMP : %0.5lf\n",time_t);
  }

  free(a);
  free(b);
  free(c);
  free(d_intel_avx_omp);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that I will get d = a * b + c but it is showing segmentation fault. I have tried to perform the same task without OpenMP and it working errorless. Please let me know if there is any compatibility issue or I am missing any part.

- gcc version 7.3.0
- Intel® Core™ i3-3110M Processor
- OS Ubuntu 18.04
- Open MP 4.5, I have executed the command `$ echo |cpp -fopenmp -dM |grep -i open` and it showed #define _OPENMP 201511
- Command to compile, `gcc first_int.c -mavx -fopenmp`

** ***UPDATE*** **

As per the discussions and suggestions, the new code is,

```
 float * a = (float *) aligned_alloc(N, sizeof(float) * N);
 float * b = (float *) aligned_alloc(N, sizeof(float) * N);
 float * c = (float *) aligned_alloc(N, sizeof(float) * N);
 float * d_intel_avx_omp = (float *)aligned_alloc(N, sizeof(float) * N);
```

This working without perfectly.

Just a note, I was trying to compare general calculations, avx calculation and avx+openmp calculation. This is the result I got,

> - Time taken to calculate without AVX : 0.00037
> - Time taken to calculate with AVX : 0.00024
> - Time taken to calculate with AVX and OMP : 0.00019

N = 50000

Comment: Please make a [mcve] to help us understand your problem better.

Comment: Platform? Compiler? Options? OpenMP version?

Comment: @P.W I have modified the code, please have a look.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I have included the info you had asked. Please have a look.

Comment: I removed the [c++] tag because the question seems totally unrelated to C++. If not, please clarify.

Comment: No, it's not guaranteed atomic, but in practice it is on some CPUs.  See and [SSE instructions: which CPUs can do atomic 16B memory operations?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7646018) [Per-element atomicity of vector load/store and gather/scatter?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46012574).  Your question body is about debugging a segfault, though; I don't see the connection with asking about atomicity of a 32-byte store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`_mm256_store_ps`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_store_ps&expand=5583) says:

> Store 256-bits (composed of 8 packed single-precision (32-bit) floating-point elements) from a into memory. **mem_addr must be aligned on a 32-byte boundary or a general-protection exception may be generated**.

You can use [`_mm256_storeu_si256`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_storeu_si256&expand=5583,5648) instead for unaligned stores.

---

A better option is to align all your arrays on a 32-byte boundary (for 256-bit avx registers) and use aligned load and stores for maximum performance because unaligned loads/stores crossing a cache line boundary incur performance penalty.

Use [`std::aligned_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc) (or C11 `aligned_alloc`, `memalign`, `posix_memalign`, whatever you have available) instead of `malloc(size)`, e.g.:

```
float* allocate_aligned(size_t n) {
    constexpr size_t alignment = alignof(__m256);
    return static_cast<float*>(aligned_alloc(alignment, sizeof(float) * n));
}
// ...
float* a = allocate_aligned(N);
float* b = allocate_aligned(N);
float* c = allocate_aligned(N);
float* d_intel_avx_omp = allocate_aligned(N);
```

In C++-17 `new` can allocate with alignment:

```
float* allocate_aligned(size_t n) {
    constexpr auto alignment = std::align_val_t{alignof(__m256)};
    return new(alignment) float[n];
}
```

---

Alternatively, use [Vc: portable, zero-overhead C++ types for explicitly data-parallel programming](https://github.com/VcDevel/Vc) that aligns heap-allocated SIMD vectors for you:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <Vc/Vc>

Vc::float_v random_float_v() {
    alignas(Vc::VectorAlignment) float t[Vc::float_v::Size];
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < Vc::float_v::Size; ++i)
        t[i] = std::rand() % 10;
    return Vc::float_v(t, Vc::Aligned);
}

unsigned reverse_crc32(void const* vbegin, void const* vend) {
    unsigned const* begin = reinterpret_cast<unsigned const*>(vbegin);
    unsigned const* end = reinterpret_cast<unsigned const*>(vend);
    unsigned r = 0;
    while(begin != end)
        r = __builtin_ia32_crc32si(r, *--end);
    return r;
}

int main() {
    constexpr size_t N = 65536;
    constexpr size_t M = N / Vc::float_v::Size;

    std::unique_ptr<Vc::float_v[]> a(new Vc::float_v[M]);
    std::unique_ptr<Vc::float_v[]> b(new Vc::float_v[M]);
    std::unique_ptr<Vc::float_v[]> c(new Vc::float_v[M]);
    std::unique_ptr<Vc::float_v[]> d_intel_avx_omp(new Vc::float_v[M]);

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
        a[i] = random_float_v();
        b[i] = random_float_v();
        c[i] = random_float_v();
    }

    auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        d_intel_avx_omp[i] = a[i] * b[i] + c[i];
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    double seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t1 - t0).count();
    unsigned crc = reverse_crc32(d_intel_avx_omp.get(), d_intel_avx_omp.get() + M); // Make sure d_intel_avx_omp isn't optimized out.
    std::printf("crc: %u, time: %.09f seconds\n", crc, seconds);
}
```

Parallel version:

```
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
// ...
    auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    tbb::parallel_for(size_t{0}, M, [&](unsigned i) {
        d_intel_avx_omp[i] = a[i] * b[i] + c[i];
    });
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

Comment: Or use _m256 pointers instead of float pointers, so that they are aligned and the compiler can know it.

Comment: @technosaurus This is the allocation function that aligns, not the pointer type.

Comment: If you use _mm256_store_ps on a properly aligned pointer, it doesn't segfault.  Using __m256 helps the compiler tell you all the screwed up ways  you are possibly misaligning it, while reducing latency on some architectures.   Yes, if you allocate on the heap you need that, but you don't need to here since the size is known at compile time.

Comment: @technosaurus The compiler doesn't care whether `__m256*` is properly aligned. The CPU at run-time does. Replacing `float*` with `__m256*` won't change that.

Comment: Yeah, my point, it can assume __m256 pointers are aligned to 32 bytes... If you use __m256 types directly, they will be aligned and it never needs unaligned loads/stores.  At runtime the CPU will have nothing to complain about.  You could even just do `static __m256 a[N];` to put it in the .bss section and avoid memalign altogether.

Comment: @technosaurus True, but the question uses heap allocation and that is the crux of the issue. In a real-world scenario that `N` probably comes at run-time. Had it used stack allocation there wouldn't be this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192730/discussion-between-technosaurus-and-maxim-egorushkin).

Comment: Thank you so much. But I am a bit confused with the definition of alligned_alloc(). 
I have mentioned in my question. The first parameter is a bit confusing. Both are working,
float * a = (float *) aligned_alloc(sizeof(float) * N, sizeof(float) * N);
float * a = (float *) aligned_alloc(N,sizeof(float) * N);

Comment: @PritamPallab Added an example for you.

Answer (score 3):

You must use aligned memory for these intrinsics. Change your `malloc(...)` to `aligned_alloc(sizeof(float) * 8, ...)` (C11).

This is completely unrelated to atomics. You are working on entirely separate pieces of data (even on different cache lines), so there is no need for any protection.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I am a bit confused with the definition of alligned_alloc(). 
I have mentioned in my question. The first parameter is a bit confusing. Both are working,
float * a = (float *) aligned_alloc(sizeof(float) * N, sizeof(float) * N);
float * a = (float *) aligned_alloc(N,sizeof(float) * N);

Comment: The first parameter is the granularity of the alignment, which is defined explicitly as 32 byte - the size of your registers - eight floats. Naturally, multiples of 32 will also work but put more constraints on allocation, so you should use exactly 32.